# discussion of, or discussion on?

Tags: grammaticality

I am editing a translation of a book on Colossians. Should the sub-heading be 'A discussion **of** Colossians 1:1-23, or **on** Colossians 1:1-23?

Comment: How about "about Colossians"?

Comment: [Visit please.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16477/when-should-i-use-a-discussion-of-vs-a-discussion-on-vs-a-discussion-abou?s=2|2.1710)