# A biography of/about/on

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

Which do I use, in the sentence 
"*I'm reading a biography ___ Winston Churchill*" ?

Comment: All three work.  I'd probably prefer "of", absent any context that would make that "clash" somehow.  (Eg, if you were writing a piece that might discuss the works of other authors, using "of" might be taken to mean Churchill wrote the biography.)

Comment: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+biography+of%2Ca+biography+on%2Ca+biography+about&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20biography%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20biography%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20biography%20about%3B%2Cc0) makes the overwhelming preference for ***of*** pretty obvious.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I disagree. If Churchill was the *author*, almost everyone would say it was *a biography **by** Churchill [**of/on** whoever he wrote about]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Like I said, you have to consider the context.  If you just discussed "the works of Shakespeare and Marlowe" then "of" would likely be interpreted to mean "authored by".

Comment: [Quite similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16477/when-should-i-use-a-discussion-of-vs-a-discussion-on-vs-a-discussion-abou)

Comment: It seems that 'of' is more formal, and 'about' or 'on' less so. Personally, in a conversational setting, I would use 'about' - but Hot Licks does have a point.

Comment: @HotLicks: I believe the point here is that it is *about* Churchill, not written by him.  If Churchill were the author, you would say it is an *autobiography*.

Comment: @zondo - The point here is to be reasonably idiomatic while managing/balancing the ever-present danger of ambiguity.  It's one of several skills that distinguishes a good writer from a mediocre one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A biography *of* Winston Churchill is the story of Churchill's life.
- A biography *about* Winston Churchill implies to me that it's the story of *someone's* life, and the subject of the book is Churchill. But if it were the story of Churchill's life it would have been a biography *of* Churchill, so I'd scratch my head and wonder how *this* book is different from that.
- A biography *on* Winston Churchill sounds like something a child would say, either informally or because they hadn't learned to use *of.* I'd know exactly what you meant, but I'd die a little inside.